# LM311 output stays at Vee regardless of input voltage

Tags: comparator

I have wired up the LM311 circuit shown in the figure below. It should work as follows (at least to my understanding), when V+ (pin 2) > V- (pin 3) the output (pin 7) should rise to 12V and when V+ < V- the output should fall to Gnd. I have applied a 1kHz square with an amplitude of 1V swinging around Gnd to pin 2 (V+), see scope image on the second picture. I expect a square wave from 0V to 12V on the output but instead it stays at approximately -12V (CH2 on the scope image), so i.e. at Vee. Even when I apply 12V on pin 2, the output stays at -12V.

**My question**: Why is this happening? Shouldn't it also produce a square wave on the output? Is there an error in my circuit?[image]
[image: LM311 circuit as wired up on breadboard]

Comment: The circuit looks OK to me.

Comment: You have fitted the pullup resistor R? ?

Comment: Are you sure that you did not swap the pin 2 with pin 3?

Comment: Vout cannot be equal -11V if pin 1 is connected to GND.

Comment: Yeah I double checked everything, I think the IC is broken

Comment: Are pins 1 and 4 shorted together internally on these chips?

Comment: @evildemonic no, they are not. The datasheet would provide this info.

Comment: @Justme The BAD chips, not correctly working ones!  Of course they are not normally shorted together.  How else would it be possible to see -Vcc on pin 1?

Answer (score 1):

Go over your connections on the hardware and make sure they are connected to the right pins/ wires/ components/etc.

I’ve connected everything together with a circuit I worked on and thought everything was fine, then the circuit is misbehaving. Two hours later I find out a resistor is connected to the wrong pin, changed it and everything was fixed!

Comment: Yeah I reconnected the circuit but it still outputs -12V. I bought this comparator on eBay from China, so I suspect it is just a broken IC.

Comment: Perhaps the IC received electrostatic damage or was a malfunctioned part. Try another LM311 if you have spare.

Comment: Yeah I also thought about that, I tested the whole batch I ordered. None of them seem to work..

Comment: This may do nothing but try using 10V positive peak input and -10V negative peak input. Keep supplies at 12 and -12V. See if this does help. Perhaps you are too close to rail voltages.

Comment: @Leoman12 Please take care to really answer the question. If you have only suggestions or want to try the OP something, use the comments.

Comment: I did, I read the Datasheet. It notes that you shouldn’t use input voltages that exceed supply voltage. Also common mode voltage is probably higher than max allowed. But it still possible work, that’s why I mentioned it as a possible solution.

Comment: OP has already tried using +1 V and -1 V swings, well within the common mode range.

Comment: But I wonder if this was after OP applied 12V/-12V to input with supplies of 12/-12V. In that case, Input common mode reached beyond maximum.

Answer (score -3):

Pins 5 and 6 are floating. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: They should be kept floating according to the datsheet (if unused)